How can I get the agent response as audio instead of text when using microphone from Dialogflow CX using javascript
`I have created an agent using dialogflow cx.
As the mic wouldn't work for the defaulted dialogflow messenger I have used the javascript so that    the mic and the functionality works. The text is working when using mic but I am not able to get  the voice. Is there a way the app could respond as a voice?
Thank you!`
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const micButton = document.getElementById('micButton');
  let recognition;

  function initializeVoiceRecognition() {
    if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
      alert('Web Speech API is not supported by this browser.');
    } else {
      recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
      recognition.continuous = false;
      recognition.interimResults = false;

      recognition.onstart = function () {
        micButton.style.color = 'blue'; // Change color to blue when recording starts
      };

      recognition.onend = function () {
        micButton.style.color = 'gray'; // Change color back to gray when recording ends
      };

      recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        const transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
        sendVoiceMessageToDialogflow(transcript);
      };

      micButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (recognition && recognition.state === 'inactive') {
          recognition.start();
        } else if (recognition) {
          recognition.stop();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  function sendVoiceMessageToDialogflow(text) {
    const dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger');
    const chatComponent = dfMessenger.shadowRoot.querySelector('df-messenger-chat');

    if (chatComponent) {
      // Simulate typing and send the message
      const input = chatComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('input');
      if (input) {
        input.value = text;
        input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

        const sendButton = dfMessenger.shadowRoot.querySelector('button.send-button');
        if (sendButton) {
          sendButton.click();
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.error('df-messenger-chat component not found.');
    }
  }

  initializeVoiceRecognition();
});


Audio Input / Output is not yet supported on Dialogflow Messenger. You can create a Feature Request here (make sure to select Template Feature Request): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=956347&pli=1&template=1504451
